# iOS RealityKit : get world position of placed object from raycast center of screen

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

Using raycast and the tap gesture, I have successfully placed multiples objects (entity and anchors) in my `arview`.

Now, I am trying to get the `entity` that is the closest to the us using the center of the screen, in order to place a object near it. So we can imagine that every time an anchor is close to the center of the phone screen, a new object "spawn"

For that I am trying to use the `raycast`, but my code  :

```
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
     // 
        if let hitEntity = arView.entity(
                at: self.arView.center
        ) {
            print("hitEntity IS FOUND !")
            print(hitEntity.name) // this is the object I previously placed

            guard let result = arView.raycast(from: self.arView.center, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any).first else { return }

           // here result is the surface behind/below the object, and not the object I want 
            return;

         }
     
    }
```

the `result` trigger on a surface, but I can't manage to get the world transform of the **object** (entity) and not the surface behind.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To get the worldTransform of the entity, you can call `hitEntity.position(relativeTo: nil)`.

If I'm not understanding your question correctly, this might help too:

To get the position of `result` relative to the entity's local space, you can call `hitEntity.convert(position: result.worldTransform, from: nil)`

Convert is a super useful method in RealityKit. There's a few different methods, but here's the documentation for the one I added above:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/hastransform/3244194-convert/

---

I hope one of those helps you!